# Chronograf chart is failing with Startup probe failed

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, influxdb, chronograf

I have [installed this chart](https://github.com/influxdata/helm-charts/tree/master/charts/chronograf#install-the-chart) on brand new GKE private cluster but it is failing with

```
  Type     Reason                             Age                     From                                   Message
  ----     ------                             ----                    ----                                   -------
  ...
  Normal   Pulled                             6m7s (x4 over 7m34s)    kubelet                                Container image "chronograf:1.9.4" already present on machine
  Normal   Created                            6m7s (x4 over 7m34s)    kubelet                                Created container chronograf
  Normal   Killing                            6m7s (x3 over 7m7s)     kubelet                                Container chronograf failed startup probe, will be restarted
  Normal   Started                            6m5s (x4 over 7m33s)    kubelet                                Started container chronograf
  Warning  Unhealthy                          5m57s (x10 over 7m27s)  kubelet                                Startup probe failed: Get "http://172.17.0.132:8888/ping": dial tcp 172.17.0.132:8888: connect: connection refused
  Warning  BackOff                            2m30s (x11 over 5m7s)   kubelet                                Back-off restarting failed container
```

Why and how to fix?

Answer (score 0):

For Google Cloud Platform at least, the problem seems to be that the startupProbe.initialDelaySeconds default (5 seconds) is too low. When I set it to 10, the chart succeeded.